# Projection of Quantum State onto Bell State

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I am very interested by [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.210403) on entanglement swapping and timelike entanglement.

The one thing I get really tripped up with is the whole idea of a projection onto a bell basis.  I understand the whole idea of projecting into different basises, but I am not sure what the authors are doing.  From the article:

```
When the two photons of time  (photons 2 and 3) are
projected onto any Bell state, the first and last photons
(1 and 4) collapse also into the same state and entanglement
is swapped. The first and last photons, that did not share
between them any correlations, become entangled.
```

I am trying to see how that is the case from Equation 3.  I am missing the way to mathematically take the projection and then see what is happening with photons 1 and 4.  Any help in understanding how to project onto the bell basis would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please make a reference in your question to the [free access paper in arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the link you have provided for the paper is only accessible for those who have a subscription to the APS journal. So maybe instead you could just give a preview of the equation you are referring to.

But I can give you a general overview on projections in quantum mechanics and Bell states. I will use [Dirac's Bra-Ket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation for the rest of this post:

Mathematically speaking, a projection of e.g. one state $\left|v\right>$ onto another state $\left|u\right>$, is just written as follows:
$$P_{u} := \left\langle u\right| v\rangle \left|u\right>$$
Where $P_u$ stands for projection onto $\left|u\right>$ and not a probability.

The $\left\langle u\right| v\rangle$ term is just the inner product between the two kets (states) in Dirac's notation.

Now in a physical sense, projection of states in quantum mechanics results from simple measurement of a system's observables, e.g. a photon's polarization, in a superposition of states $\left|\psi\right>= \alpha \left|H\right> + \beta \left|V\right>$ once measured, can collapse (be projected) onto one of its eigenstates, being horizontal or vertical polarization in this case.

As for Bell states, each Bell state describes a unique maximally entangled state of two qubits(photons e.g.). Meaning all 4 Bell states together: (A and B to distinguish between the photons) 
$$\left|\Phi_{\pm}^{AB}\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|H^{A},H^{B}\right> \pm \left|V^{A},V^{B}\right>\right) $$
$$\left|\Psi_{\pm}^{AB}\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|H^{A},V^{B}\right> \pm \left|V^{A},H^{B}\right>\right)  $$
form a basis in the Hilbert space $H_4^{AB}$ of 2-qubit entangled states. So as shown before, here one can also talk about the projection of two qubit states onto a given Bell state, using the same formula. An example to showcase: 
If the Bell states are said to form a complete basis for 2-qubit states, then for any given 2-qubit state, one should be able to decompose and express it in terms of superpositon of Bell states. Simply meaning that you project the 2-qubit state on each one of the Bell states. For example lets see whether the state $\left|v\right>=\left|H^{A},V^{B}\right>$ has a non-vanishing probability of collapsing (being projected after measurement) onto the first Bell state:
\begin{align*}
\left\langle v\right| \Phi_+^{AB}\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left\langle V^{B},H^{A}\right| \left(\left|H^{A},H^{B}\right> + \left|V^{A},V^{B}\right>\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left\langle V^{B},H^{A}\right| \left|H^{A},H^{B}\right> + \left\langle V^{B},H^{A}\right| \left|V^{A},V^{B}\right>\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left\langle H^{A}\right| H^{A}\rangle \left\langle V^{B}\right| H^{B}\rangle + \left\langle H^{A}\right| V^{A}\rangle \left\langle V^{B}\right| V^{B}\rangle\right)\\
&= 0 
\end{align*}
So we see that such projection is impossible, a result which is expected as $\left|H^{A},V^{B}\right>$ is not an entangled state since it can be written down as a single outer product of the individual kets.

I hope this overview gives you enough insight to be able to follow the mathematical steps involved in the paper you're reading.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the Bell States form a basis of an 'entangled' Hilbert space.  What I mean is any entangled state can be represented by a projection onto these states?

Comment: Yes, but note that it forms a complete basis only for two-qubit systems. So yes if you have any pair of entangled qubits, you can represent them in a superposition of Bell states.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the photon with the entangled state already collapsed (and therefore correlated to the first photon) is just impacting the reading on the second entangled pair, as opposed to some time-traversing effect?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4191), the time-like Bell states are :

$|\psi^\pm\rangle^{\tau, \tau'}_{ab} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|h_a^\tau v_b^{\tau'}\rangle \pm |h_a^\tau v_b^{\tau'}\rangle)$

$|\phi^\pm\rangle^{\tau, \tau'}_{ab} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|h_a^\tau h_b^{\tau'}\rangle \pm |v_a^\tau v_b^{\tau'}\rangle)$

So, equation $(3)$ just reexpress $|S\rangle = |\psi^-\rangle^{0, \tau}_{ab} \otimes |\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, 2\tau}_{ab}$, which represents a tensor product of a particles $1(0),2(\tau)$ states times a particles $3(\tau),4(2\tau)$ state, in a decomposition on Bell states at equal times Bell states at different times:  $|S\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|\psi^-\rangle^{0, 2\tau}_{ab} \otimes |\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, \tau}_{ab} + ...)$  (just chek with the definition of the  $\phi, \psi$ above that the decomposition is correct)

So, if you project, for instance, the $2,3$ particles on a equal times Bell state as $|\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, \tau}_{ab}$, then the $1,4$ particles are entangled because they are projected in the Bell state $|\psi^-\rangle^{0, 2\tau}_{ab}$

Comment: So I have that state |S>.  If I want to project it onto $|\psi^{\tau,\tau}_{ab}$,  then I take $\langle \psi|S\rangle|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: And then this should result in 1 and 4 being projected into that other bell state?

Comment: Yes to your second question. For your first question, by measurement of a $2,3$ particle state ($|\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, \tau}_{ab}$), $|S\rangle$ is projected on the state    $|\psi^-\rangle^{0, 2\tau}_{ab} \otimes |\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, \tau}_{ab}$, so you have : $\langle\psi^-|^{0, 2\tau}_{ab} \otimes \langle\psi^-|^{\tau, \tau}_{ab} |S\rangle = \frac{1}{2}$, and finally the projection of $|S\rangle$ is $\langle\psi^-|^{0, 2\tau}_{ab} \otimes \langle\psi^-|^{\tau, \tau}_{ab} |S\rangle   |S\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|\psi^-\rangle^{0, 2\tau}_{ab} \otimes |\psi^-\rangle^{\tau, \tau}_{ab}$